# Fragment A does not pause when Fragment B is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments, let's call the first fragment `Fragment A` and the second fragment `Fragment B`. `Fragment A` contains a `ViewPager` with 2 child fragments and `Fragment B` is a single fragment that will get some data points from the user in some way. One of `Fragment A`'s child fragments contains a `RecyclerView` which should update it's cardview with the data point from `Fragment B`. Both fragments are replaced inside a `FrameLayout`.

The problem is that `notifiyDatasetChanged` is never called for `Fragment A`s `RecyclerView` because `Fragment A is never called`. When I hit the back button from `Fragment B` it doesn't update the `RecyclerView` with the new data.

How can I get Fragment A to pause or call `onStop` when I open `Fragment B`? What is the best way to update the `RecyclerView`?

**Fragment A's transaction**

```
// ViewPager fragment
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, ViewPagerFragment.newInstance());
    ft.commit();
```

**Fragment B's transaction**

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, SessionFragment.newInstance());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

**OnBackPressed**

```
 /*
When a fragment is open allow you to go back to the activity when back button is pressed
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (onBackPressed(fragmentManager)) {
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}


private boolean onBackPressed(FragmentManager fm) {
    if (fm != null) {
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }

        List<Fragment> fragList = fm.getFragments();
        if (fragList != null && fragList.size() > 0) {
            for (Fragment frag : fragList) {
                if (frag == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (frag.isVisible()) {
                    if (onBackPressed(frag.getChildFragmentManager())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**______________________ LOG INFO _____________________**

```
12-22 05:38:00.268  18255-18255/? E/InputEventSender﹕ Exception dispatching finished 

signal.
12-22 05:38:00.268  18255-18255/? E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-22 05:38:00.278  18255-18255/? E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.Vector.lastElement(Vector.java:621)
            at com.project.ui.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:267)
            at com.project.ui.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:251)
            at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
            at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-22 05:38:00.278  18255-18255/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-22 05:38:00.280  18255-18255/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: example.com.project, PID: 18255
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.Vector.lastElement(Vector.java:621)
            at com.project.ui.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:267)
            at com.project.ui.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:251)
            at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
            at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: you need to manually call the onPause method of the fragment before replacing it.

Comment: Can you show me some example code? And best practices for this?

Comment: yes what you can do is this, take up a stack and push the first fragment A.. When you need to replace A with B, then  in that case, replace push the new Fragment B into the stack and before that pick the last element and call onPause

Comment: I thought replacing it would pause it, calling ft.replace(...) I thought would pause a fragment if you are using the same FrameLayout. Can you write out some pseudo code for this in an answer below? If it works I will accept your answer

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a stack object

```
Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack = new Stack<Fragment>();
```

When the fragment A is replaced the first time do this:

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
mViewPagerFragment = ViewPagerFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, mViewPagerFragment);
fragmentStack.push(mViewPagerFragment);
ft.commit();
```

When you have to replace A with B, do this:

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmnetStack.lastElement().onPause();
mSessionFragment = SessionFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, mSessionFragment );
fragmentStack.push(mSessionFragment );
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

On calling the back button, do this to get the fragment A back

```
fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
fragmentStack.pop();
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
mViewPagerFragment = fragmentStack.lastElement();
mViewPagerFragment.onResume();
ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, mViewPagerFragment);
ft.commit();
```

**EDIT:**

Before adding fragment b, remove fragment A like this:

```
 fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());
 // then add the other code to add fragment B
```

you will have to do the same when trying to move from B -> A

Comment: checked but did not work error is NoSuchElementException

Comment: i guess ul have to remove the previous fragment first , wait check the edit

Comment: Maybe it was my mistake in not explaining clearly enough. There is a recyclerview in the second child fragment of my viewpager which is in fragment A. In the activity that holds both fragment A and B, fragment A is started initially, then there is a button to inflate fragment B and .replace, my problem is that the values obtained in fragment B do not store properly in fragment A's child recyclerview. I checked the log statements and onResume is not being called for some weird reason ??

Comment: try removing Fragment A before adding Fragment B, and then adding it again when moving back.. i am sure it might work in your old code also..

Comment: unfortunately still not working, here is how my code looks: http://pastebin.com/LP3pKfQH

Comment: Same error occurs, which is NoSuchElementException, I'm pretty tired it's 6 am here so I think I'll pass out for now thanks for the attempt :P

Comment: i cant access the link.. :)... Post the log if possible

Comment: will post log info in original post... log posted now, I essentially just changed fragmentStack.pop() to ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop()) when adding Fragment B and resuming Fragment A

Comment: in the onBack press method, check the size of the stack before popping the last element..